# Gemfile:22: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I run bundle install against the gemfile source below, I get a gemfile syntax error that points to the 'better errors' gem which is the second to last line.

When I run ruby -c Gemfile. I get the following message

Gemfile:22: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input
    gem 'better_errors'

Any ideas?

```
source 'https://rubygems.org' 
ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
 # Rails defaults
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0' 
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0' 
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

# learn-rails
gem 'activerecord-tableless' 
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'gibbon'
gem 'google_drive'
gem 'high_voltage'
gem 'simple_form', '>= 3.0.0.r  
group :development do
    gem 'better_errors'
    gem 'quiet_assets'
end ￼
```

Thank you for any assistance and time.

Comment: Syntax highlighting makes the error rather obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed the closing `'` here :

```
gem 'simple_form', '>= 3.0.0.r <~~~
group :development do
    gem 'better_errors'
    gem 'quiet_assets'
end
```

**Corrected**

```
gem 'simple_form', '>= 3.0.0.r'
group :development do
    gem 'better_errors'
    gem 'quiet_assets'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

After your version number specification for gem `"simple_form"`:

```
">= 3.0.0.r\ngroup :development do\n    gem "
```

(which is already invalid), you cannot continue another token `better_errors` without having a comma (which would be invalid anyway).

Comment: The issue I just found,that OP missed to close the string `gem 'simple_form', '>= 3.0.0.r`. Thus the error came. :)